How can I get the InvokePattern of an UI element if IsInvokePatternAvailable is true
I'm trying to do some automation actions using UI Automation. I can get the target UI element by code. And I can see its property IsInvokePatternAvailable is true. But when I tried to get the InvokePattern it shows me "System.InvalidOperationException: Unsupported Pattern."
Then I want to check what are the supported patterns by the API "GetSupportedPatterns", and I found there was only one pattern "SelectionItemPattern".
Interestingly, if I use the Inovke.invoke command from the action menu of Inspect.exe, it works.
So I suppose there should be a method that can be invoked. The issue has blocked me a couple of days. Who can give me some clues?
Exception
Inspect Tool
How found:  Focus
Name:   "Select group:"
ControlType:    UIA_ListItemControlTypeId (0xC357)
LocalizedControlType:   "list item"
BoundingRectangle:  {l:642 t:280 r:770 b:293}
IsEnabled:  true
IsOffscreen:    false
IsKeyboardFocusable:    true
HasKeyboardFocus:   true
AccessKey:  ""
ProcessId:  12956
RuntimeId:  [2A.32270.4.80000001.32270.FFFFFFFC.1]
ProviderDescription:    "[pid:12956,providerId:0x0 Annotation:Microsoft: Annotation Proxy (unmanaged:UIAutomationCore.dll); Main(parent link):Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (unmanaged:UIAutomationCore.dll)]"
IsPassword: false
HelpText:   ""
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId:  1
LegacyIAccessible.DefaultAction:    "Double Click"
LegacyIAccessible.Description:  ""
LegacyIAccessible.Help: ""
LegacyIAccessible.KeyboardShortcut: ""
LegacyIAccessible.Name: "Select group:"
LegacyIAccessible.Role: list item (0x22)
LegacyIAccessible.State:    selected,focused,focusable,selectable (0x300006)
LegacyIAccessible.Value:    ""
SelectionItem.IsSelected:   true
SelectionItem.SelectionContainer:   "" list
IsAnnotationPatternAvailable:   false
IsDragPatternAvailable: false
IsDockPatternAvailable: false
IsDropTargetPatternAvailable:   false
IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable:   false
IsGridItemPatternAvailable: false
IsGridPatternAvailable: false
IsInvokePatternAvailable:   true
IsItemContainerPatternAvailable:    false
IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable:    true
IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable: false
IsObjectModelPatternAvailable:  false
IsRangeValuePatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollItemPatternAvailable:   true
IsScrollPatternAvailable:   false
IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable:    true
IsSelectionPatternAvailable:    false
IsSpreadsheetItemPatternAvailable:  false
IsSpreadsheetPatternAvailable:  false
IsStylesPatternAvailable:   false
IsSynchronizedInputPatternAvailable:    false
IsTableItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsTablePatternAvailable:    false
IsTextChildPatternAvailable:    false
IsTextEditPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPattern2Available:    false
IsTogglePatternAvailable:   false
IsTransformPatternAvailable:    false
IsTransform2PatternAvailable:   false
IsValuePatternAvailable:    false
IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable:  false
IsWindowPatternAvailable:   false
FirstChild: [null]
LastChild:  [null]
Next:   "xxx" list item
Previous:   [null]
Other Props:    Object has no additional properties
Children:   Container has no children
Ancestors:  "" list

AutomationElementCollection mats = list1.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem));

            foreach (AutomationElement mat in mats)
            {
                InvokePattern matInvoke = (InvokePattern)mat.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern);
                matInvoke.Invoke();
            }

